# Apache Solr - index data

Tags: apache, solr

I have two tables: tableA and tableB. There is one to many relationship between this tables. One row in tableA corresponds to multiple rows in tableB. I have query:

```
select aa.id, aa.first_name, aa.last_name, bb.address_home, bb.address_coresp from testA aa, testB bb where aa.id = bb.testA_fk;
```

which returns many rows - 3 for example:

```
1   John    Terry   HOME 1      CORESP_1
1   John    Terry   HOME 11     CORESP_11
1   John    Terry   HOME 111    CORESP_111
```

When I insert this query into solr`s data-config.xml file and index data, then the result is:

```
{"address_home": ["HOME 111"],
"address_coresp": ["CORESP_111"],
"id": "1",
"LAST_NAME": "Terry",
"FIRST_NAME": "John",
"_version_": 1513906493806608400
}
```

There is only one address result instead of three.

Fragment of my data-config.xml:

```
<document name="testDoc">

<entity name="testA" query="select aa.id, aa.first_name, aa.last_name, bb.address_home, bb.address_coresp from testA aa, testB bb where aa.id = bb.testA_fk">
    <field column="id" name="id" />
    <field column="first_name" name="first_name" />
    <field column="last_name" name="last_name" />
    <field column="address_home" name="address_home" />
    <field column="address_coresp" name="address_coresp" />
</entity>
</document>
```

and in schema.xml I have multiValued set to true:

```
<field name="address_home" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" /><field name="address_coresp" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

I know that the solution for my problem is nested entity element:

```
<entity name="testA" query="select * from testA">
field definitions...
    <entity name="testB" query="select * from testB where testB.a_id = '${testA.id}'">
    field definitions...
</entity>
</entity
```

, but is there an option to do that in one query. I want to achieve this result:

```
    {"id": "1",
    "LAST_NAME": "Terry",
    "FIRST_NAME": "John",
    "address_home": ["HOME 1","HOME 11","HOME 111"],
    "address_coresp": ["CORESP_1","CORESP_11","CORESP_111"],
    "_version_": 1513905361988354000
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your schema.xml for the value of uniqueKey, I suspect it is set to "id":

```
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Therefore, each subsequent record with an id of "1" is overwriting the last, resulting in only the last record with an id of "1" being retained in the index.

If you need to be able to update the documents in Solr when the data changes in the database, you could use the id from TableB, or a composition of id's in TableA and TableB.  If you do not need to update, you could map the id field to a different Solr field and let Solr auto-generate the unique id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Solr does not recognise my records as unique because the id was the same for every record. I have tested the solution with id from table B and it doesn`t look like I wanted. I will have to use nested entities.